# Batch conversion from json to parquet in python?

Tags: python, json, parquet

I have hundreds of json files need to be coverted to parquet files. I know we can read the json to pandas dataframe with pd.read_json and then save to parquet file using df.to_parquet. But the challenge is how to do it efficiently with hundreds of files.

Anybody know how to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: The parquet format is well-documented, so you could certainly roll your own conversion.  The question is, would it be worth it?  The time-per-conversion savings will be small, so if this is a one-time thing, then you should probably just let pandas do it.

Comment: Hi Tim, my main motivation is to reduce file size. I believe parquet file size is much smaller than json. I have ~30gb size of Json file which is almost impossible to read all of them into pandas dataframe. Any workaround? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiprocessing to convert multiple files at once, in the convert function put your code, if you need to you could change `filePath` to the contents as a string or array and then also change the values of `files`

```
import multiprocessing

def convert(filePath):
    # Put the conversion code here

files = ["file1.json", "file2.json"]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10) as pool: # You can change the number of processes
        pool.map(convert, files) # Tells multiprocessing to run the convert function with all of the file paths
```

Comment: great idea, I will give it a try. Thank you!